# What are some tips for leveling up?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

Where can I find a good guide that focuses on efficiently leveling-up for LOTRO?

Comment: As an aside, LotRO is really a game you shouldn't bother power-leveling. There is a lot of fantastic content on the road to 65 that you would bypass. Also, when you get to 65 via power-leveling, you end up having to grind out traits... very boring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mmorsrsel](http://lotro.mmorsel.com/p/lord-of-rings-online-leveling-guide.html) has a section of their site for fast leveling. I think they describe it best when they say lotro isn't really the game to fast level through. They will describe what traits/deeds you should be finishing along the way because what is a level capped player with no virtues.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a few dollars to spend, I've found [KillerGuides](http://www.killerguides.com/) to be a reasonably good resource for these kinds of guides.  I leveled up from 0 to mid sixties in under a week with their guide.

Comment: Although I don't see anything suggesting they've been updated for RoI...might want to wait now that it's released.

Answer (score 1):

I run quests trying to accomplish the epic book quests 2-3 levels under the recommended level until I hit level 20, after which I run mostly Epic Book quests and skirmishes until level 45-50 depending on the character. Then, everything in Moria and after. If you're a VIP (subscribed), running skirmishes is the absolute fastest way to level.

Comment: Skirmishes are not just for VIP's anymore. Free/Premium get the First Two.